# How do I extract a binary pattern from a 1D signal?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I need help for my school project. I am taking pictures from a webcam and sampling the center of the picture to get a binary reading (0/1).

The signal looks like this:

`000011111000000000000000011111000000111110000011111111110000000000011111111111111110000011111111110000000000011111000001111`

I need this bit string that matches the sampled data:

`010001010110011101100101`

How do I sample the signal to get the bit string?

[image: plot]

Plotting code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
fig.set_size_inches(20, 10)
ax[0].step(np.arange(len(samples)), samples, 'o-', where='post')
ax[1].step(np.arange(len(desired)) * 5.2, desired, 'o-', where='post')
plt.show()
```

Code that reads from a video camera and produces the 1D signal:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test3.mp4")

binaries = []

def colorRecognizer():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    height, width, _ = frame.shape

    cx = int(width / 2)
    cy = int(height / 2)

    video_center = hsv_frame[cy, cx]
    hsv_value = video_center[2]

    cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 20, (0, 242, 40), 6)
    cv2.imshow("Black/White recognition", frame)
    
    if hsv_value <= 10:
        color = "black"
        binaries.append(1) 
    elif hsv_value >= 100:
        color = "white"
        binaries.append(0)
    else:
        color = "Undefined color"
          
while cap.isOpened():
    colorRecognizer()
    print(''.join(map(str,binaries)))
        
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please add the input image so others can reproduce your issue. Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: you're getting one result per frame, and your camera gives you 30 frames per second probably, so you will get 30 characters added to the list/string for every second. -- you should **plot** this stuff, with matplotlib.

Comment: I've rewritten your question and added plots. now it's clearer. you need to **"recover the clock"** from your signal. that requires having an initial guess for the "clock" (looks like 5 samples per bit), then finding edges and aligning the "time" to the signal, and sampling once for every bit time. -- real-world implementations have to deal with noisy or "bouncing" signals, say by implementing hysteresis on analog values (don't binarize that early)